# Is the current Theme version number cached somewhere?

Tags: theme-development

I need access to my Theme's version number a number of times on each Admin Page view.

Right now I'm using `get_theme_data` which in turn parses the Theme's `style.css` file via `get_file_data`, so `style.css` gets parsed multiple times.

Is there a built-in caching mechanism for this data? Or should I just build a thin *in-process* caching wrapper around `get_theme_data`?

Thanks!

Comment: This ticket (and associated commits) may be of interest to you: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time, keep using your method.  But as @helenhousandi linked in a comment, WordPress 3.4 will be introducing a new `WP_Theme` object that will make this much easier.

Right now, you're using `get_theme_data()` to return an array with the theme's version.  No, it's not cached ... but you could likely cache it yourself in a transient if you're accessing it a lot.

```
function my_get_theme_version() {
    $value = get_transient( 'theme_version' );
    if ( !$value ) {
        $info = get_theme_data( /* theme filename */ );
        $value = $info[ 'Version' ];

        // Cache the value for 12 hours.
        set_transient( 'theme_version', $value, 60 * 60 * 12 );
    }

    return $value;
}
```

But in WP 3.4, `get_theme_data()` will be deprecated and will instead serve as a wrapper for the new `WP_Theme` API (meaning the above code will still work, but will trigger a deprecation notice).

So instead, you could use this:

```
function my_get_theme_version() {
    $theme_file = /* theme filename */;
    $theme = new WP_Theme( basename( dirname( $theme_file ) ), dirname( dirname( $theme_file ) ) );

    return $theme->get('Version');
}
```

The new object has some level of caching built in.  I encourage you to read the discussion surrounding the new changes and to follow the Codex for when it's officially documented as well.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I'll actually just cache it in-process using a PHP static variable (I mostly just not want multiple file parsings for each page view).

Comment: I usually advise against using static vars for caching ... it's easy to forget to remove them and, if the PHP process is long-running, you can easily create a memory leak by mistake when old static vars hang around.